# google calendar api (ruby) event insert error: Missing end time

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-api-client

I'm using a service account and attempting to insert an event into a calendar. I'm using the ruby bindings. I constantly get an error

> Missing end time

even though i am sending an end time!

my insert code looks like this

```
event = {start: DateTime.now, end: (DateTime.now + 0.5)}
result = client.execute( api_method: calendar.events.insert, 
   parameters:{calendarId: 'MYCALENDARID@group.calendar.google.com'}, 
   authorization: client.authorization, 
   headers: { "Content-Type" => "application/json" }, 
   body: JSON.dump(event))
```

as you can tell, the event has a start and end date! based on some old SO answers i also tried:

- sticking the body in an array (like `body: [JSON.dump(event)]`) which resulted in an exception (`undefined method`bytesize' for #`)
- using a body_object property instead (like `body_object: event`), same issue

and for reference, the setup looks like:

```
require 'google/api_client'
require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
require 'google/api_client/auth/installed_app'

client = Google::APIClient.new(:application_name => 'Example Ruby application',:application_version => '1.0.0')
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12('MYKEY.p12', 'notasecret')
client.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
:token_credential_uri => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',:audience => 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',:scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
issuer: 'MYSERVICEACCOUNT@developer.gserviceaccount.com', signing_key: key)
client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
calendar = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) give the following Ruby example:

```
event = {
  'summary' => 'Appointment',
  'location' => 'Somewhere',
  'start' => {
    'dateTime' => '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00'
  },
  'end' => {
    'dateTime' => '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00'
  },
  'attendees' => [
    {
      'email' => 'attendeeEmail'
    },
    #...
  ]
}
result = client.execute(:api_method => service.events.insert,
                        :parameters => {'calendarId' => 'primary'},
                        :body => JSON.dump(event),
                        :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
print result.data.id
```

Suggest you confirm that your code that outputs the start/end date times `{start: DateTime.now, ...}` is actually creating the nested `{'start' => {'dateTime' => '2011-....'}, ...}` that you need.

I don't know Ruby, but my guess is that `{'start' => {'dateTime' => DateTime.now}, ...}` will do what you need (for both start and end datetimes) .

Comment: thanks, i totally missed the ruby tab there and was looking at the java which is really not relevant here.